# Having a tex template ready when creating a new file

Tags: templates

We know that in Windows system, a right click menu has a new file option, with which you can create several different files, such as text document, Microsoft office documents (if installed), etc. I am wondering if I can add a new option which creates a new file that is a designated tex template. Not sure this is the best place to ask but I am hoping someone's done so.

Comment: One possibility would be to create a text document with the tex extension.  This wouldn't get you the template part of your question, but many of the experienced people around here tend to look down on templates - they end up accumulating a bunch of packages that you don't actually need but conflict with what you do need.

Comment: @Teepeemm I am not talking about those fancy templates. Even having only these lines is fine: `\documentclass{article}`,`\begin{document}`,`\end{document}`. But if this is possible there is no reason not to do more.

Comment: Although this is kind of off-topic, it’s possible to [add an item to the Windows new file context menu that creates a file from a template.](https://superuser.com/a/46952)

Comment: TexnicCenter has a File->New->File from Template option, but I've never used it.  I always just copy an old .tex file and modify.

Comment: If you are using vim, `ultisnip` plugin is a perfect choice.

Comment: What you’re asking for your depends strongly on the front-end editor you employ. So do please tell us which editor you use at present and if you’d be willing to switch editors.

Comment: @Mico I am using WinEdt 10.3, and I'd be willing to try a new one.

Comment: You might have a look at `texplate` that's included in all TeX distributions.